# How to post an array of objects by a checkbox

Tags: angular, spring, typescript, checkbox, ngfor

I'm trying to initialize an array of objet type attribute checkbox but it doesn't work. (Sorry for my bad English)

**MODELS**

*Actif*

```
import {TypeActif} from './model.type-actif';
import {CritereActif} from './model.critere-actif';

export class Actif{
  ref: string;
  nom: string = '';
  type_actif: TypeActif = new TypeActif();
  lesCriteresActifs: Array<CritereActif> = new Array<CritereActif>();
}
```

*CritereActif*

```
import {Actif} from './model.actif';
import {LesCriteres} from './model.les-criteres';
import {LesValeurs} from './model.les-valeurs';

export class CritereActif{
  id: number;
  actif: Actif = new Actif();
  critere: LesCriteres = new LesCriteres();
  valeur: LesValeurs = new LesValeurs();
}
```

*LesCriteres*

```
export class LesCriteres{
  code: string = null;
  nom: string = '';
}
```

**actif.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Critères : </label>&nbsp;
    <div class="checkbox-inline" *ngFor="let l of lesCriteres; let i= index">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" [value]="l.code" [(ngModel)]="actif.lesCriteresActifs[i].critere.code">{{l.code}}
      </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add in the table "lesCritesActifs" each element of "lesCriteres" that the user will check.

Everything worked before I added in the  the line :

```
[(ngModel)]="actif.lesCriteresActifs[i].critere.code"
```

I have this error in the web developpement console :

```
ERROR TypeError: "_co.actif.lesCriteresActifs[_v.context.index] is undefined"
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i see is you have an array of CritereActif that has to be initialized. If you know the size you can use a for loop something like:

```
for (let i = 0; i<lesCriteresActifs.length; i++){
    let aCritereActif = new CritereActif();
    lesCriteresActifs.push(aCritereActif);  
}
```

After that you can access each member of the array as you write in your program `[(ngModel)]="actif.lesCriteresActifs[i].critere.code"`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your  `lesCriteresActifs` is empty and you are trying to access to one index into `.lesCriteresActifs[_v.context.index]` then thats why is undefined and you can not acess to `.critere.code`

A partial solution could be

```
[(ngModel)]="actif.lesCriteresActifs[i]?.critere.code"
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work ! i have an other error when i try to post the data

Comment: how can i add a new objet in the table ?

Comment: I think you are getting another error because you need to validate your data. can you share me the new error?

Comment: ERROR TypeError: "null has no properties"

Comment: I think you will need to add relevant code like how are you getting the data, because as the issue is is solved.

Comment: it is true that your solution avoids errors but I had to initialize the table to avoid errors. Thank you very much for clarifying the errors.

Comment: i added this code in the actif.component.ts :  for (let i = 0; i<2; i++){
      let aCritereActif = new CritereActif();
      this.actif.lesCriteresActifs.push(aCritereActif);
    }

Comment: Then did you fix it ?

Comment: Yeah i fixed it